# Windows WebView is not able to invoke script function wrapped by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, uwp

I have UWP C# app and I am trying to invoke my javascript function from code like this:

```
webView.InvokeScriptAsync("myCoolFunc", new List<string> { });
```

Everything is fine if I have function in *.html file like this:

```
<Script>
    function myCoolFunc() {
        //do something...
    }
</Script>
```

If I use webpack and I move content of generated bundle file into script tags my function is not called.
Webpack wraps my function something like this:

```
<Script>
    ...
    (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    "use strict";
    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(process) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    const store_1 = __webpack_require__(8);
    function myCoolFunc() {
        //do something...
    }
    exports.updateMyFunc = updateMyFunc;
    ...
</Script>
```

How should I set webpack.config or webView.invokeFunction to properly call my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A public access function

If you don't want to make your method public, you could write just a "communicator" function, that will call your webpack-wrapped `myCoolFunc()` like the following:

```
<Script>
    function uwpCommunicator( functionToCall ) {
        if ( functionToCall === "myCoolFunc" ){
            //call myCoolFunc();
        }
    }
</Script>
```

### Eval

You can also run arbitrary script on the page using the `eval` function:

```
await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "//your JS code" });
```